# Jersey WebTarget vs HTTPURLConnection

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm learning web services using Java. I'm technically a noob, this is the code I've written, which works, I just don't know which method has what advantage over another, like which one is more secure? Which one will be more faster?
I'm not asking for complete too broad an answer. A short concise one will do.
I've created a REST service using Jersey 2.x and I've created client to consume the said REST service.

POST resource is as follows,

```
@POST
@Path("postactivity")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createActivity(
        @QueryParam("id") int id,
        @QueryParam("description") String description,
        @QueryParam("duration") int duration,
        @QueryParam("name")String name)
{
    //My code that creates Activity object from QueryParams is here.
}
```

Now I've created a Client which is a Java Application. I'm consume the above REST Service above in following two ways.

**Method 1** *Using HTTPURLConnection*

```
    private static void doPost(){
    QueryString qs = new QueryString("id", "123"); //QueryString is a class created to build query, not important to the question.
    qs.add("duration", "12");
    qs.add("description", "This is description");
    qs.add("name", "This is Name");
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/webservices/webapi/activities/activity?" + qs;

    URL obj;
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla 5.0");
        con.setDoOutput(true);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        Activity activity = GSON.fromJson(response.toString(), Activity.class); //This is for checking if i'm getting correct data back which I'm sending.


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

**Method 2** *Using WebTarget available via Jersey*

```
private static void doPost(){
    Response entity = webTarget
            .path("activities/postactivity")
            .queryParam("id",2204)
            .queryParam("description","Foo")
            .queryParam("duration",100)
            .queryParam("name", "Bar")
            .request()
            .post(null);
    String entityRead = entity.readEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println(entityRead);
    Activity activityRead = GSON.fromJson(entityRead, Activity.class);
    }
```

**Thanks.**

Comment: Could you please point out the problem? The implementation works for you, what would you like to have? Currently it looks like you would like to overview all the ways to consume a RESTful Web Service.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov I just want to know which of the two is recommended and if using one has some advantage/disadvantage over other.

Answer (score 0):

Honestyl i have two things to write to you:
1. The HttpURLConnection is the Java personal way of doing a retrieve of a web affiliate (like web services) but you have a better and stress-free way of doing it with Jersey and this will make things faster and smoother for you. For some persons they even say that the Jersey style is the High-level API while the HttpURLConnection is called the low-level API.
2. Your question was able to provide me with a necessary solution to a problem i have had for the past two days with consuming a @Queryparam POST webmethod. I really appreciate this.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an helpful answer and would fit better as a comment